# Is it possible to have docker running inside of virtualbox on OSX host?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, hyper-v, docker, imac

I am running windows server 2016 in virtual box for my testing needs Docker seems to allow running diff environments in containers, therefore

Inside of my OSX 10.14.1 host can I run docker in windows server 2016 guest and use different images and containers to develop, build and test? and how would I enable hyper-v in virtual box to fulfill the requirements of docker.

Comment: As for windows it works [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65546235/3140992)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** *This is reported to work online but it appears Virtualbox won't actually pass through the instructions so it can't be done.*

---

If you really wanted to enable hyper-v inside virtualbox running a windows guest, run this on the guest in PowerShell:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature –Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V –All -NoRestart

Install-WindowsFeature RSAT-Hyper-V-Tools -IncludeAllSubFeature

Install-WindowsFeature RSAT-Clustering -IncludeAllSubFeature

Install-WindowsFeature Multipath-IO

Restart-Computer
```

As per [Bleepingcomputer](https://www.baswijdenes.com/portfolio/hyper-v-in-virtualbox-guide/)

Comment: That info doesn't work.  VirtualBox doesn't pass through what you need from the CPU.  You can install the Hyper-V role, but not actually run any VMs.  See the comments after the article.